# Fake network connection as disconnected android

Tags: android, networking, mobile, android-wifi, xposed

I want to know if there is a way to fake network connection as disconnected or disabled on selected apps. As there are Xposed modules like "Fake Wifi Connection" is working, I believe this should be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: okay, please tell me if I'm being impolite or something not good before downvoting. So I know where I should not be asking.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we check network is connected or not by using something like this

```
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        isConnected = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

So you can hook method isConnectedOrConnectiong() of NetworkInfo class using Xposed and return true from it.

```
        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(NetworkInfo.class, loadPackageParam.classLoader, "isConnectedOrConnecting", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                super.beforeHookedMethod(param);
                param.setResult(false);

            }
        });
```

param.setResult(false) skips the call to the original method and returns false as a result of the call ( which is never made )

I hope this helps.

Edit: 
from the android docs

> getActiveNetworkInfo Added in API level 1
>
> NetworkInfo getActiveNetworkInfo ()
>
> Returns details about the currently active default data network. When
>   connected, this network is the default route for outgoing connections.
>   You should always check isConnected() before initiating network
>   traffic. This may return null when there is no default network.

So the call may return null when there is no default network. This will not work in that case.

Comment: if it helped you please accept it as answer or tell me what else do you want so that I can improve my answer. Thank you!